# haskell network io hgetline

Tags: networking, haskell, bytestring

I want to read all the data on a handle, and then block waiting for more data.  listen1 stops when there is a '\n' character in the stream.  listen2 works and could be made completely general by imitating the code for hGetNonBlocking.  What is the best way to do this?

```
import qualified Data.ByteString as B

loop = sequence_ . repeat

listen1 :: Handle -> TChan B.ByteString -> IO()
listen1 sock chan = do
  loop ( do
         s <- B.hGetLine sock
         atomically (writeTChan chan s)
       )

listen2 :: Handle -> TChan B.ByteString -> IO()
listen2 sock chan = do
  loop ( do
         s <- B.hGet sock 1
         s1 <- B.hGetNonBlocking sock 65000
         atomically (writeTChan chan (B.append s s1))
       )
```

Comment: BTW, `loop` is already in the standard libraries as `forever`.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you are unaware or perhaps I misunderstand your goal, but [network-bytestring](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/network-bytestring/0.1.3/doc/html/Network-Socket-ByteString-Lazy.html#v%3AgetContents) does what you want already.